# Convert VC++ library using namespace to BCB6

Tags: visual-c++, c++builder, c++builder-6

VC++ code:

```cpp
namespace Test { class __declspec(dllexport) A { public: void foo(); }; }
```

Took from library compiled in MS VC++:

```
A@Test@
```

The same in BCB6 C++:

```
@Test@A
```

What is it connected with?

What compiler options to set to record the namespace in front of the class? Because of this, BCB6 cannot link the library.

Searched on Google but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Different compilers *decorate*/*mangle* exported symbols differently.  There is no option to make BCB's compiler decorate/mangle its symbols the same way that VC++ does, and vice versa.

In any case, you can't use a *pre-compiled* VC++ `.lib` file in BCB at all, as `.lib` files are compiler-specific.

If the VC++ `.lib` is a static library, you would have to *recompile* the library's source code using BCB's compiler.

If the VC++ `.lib` is an import library for a DLL, can create a new BCB-compatible import `.lib` file, by using either:

- BCB's [COFF2OMF tool](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/COFF2OMF.EXE,_the_Import_Library_Conversion_Tool) to convert the VC++ `.lib` file itself into a new file in BCB's OMF format.
- BCB's [IMPLIB tool](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/IMPLIB.EXE,_the_Import_Library_Tool_for_Win32), which can create a new `.lib` file from the DLL itself.